# Stop jquery-ui datepicker on cancelation the confirmation box

Tags: jquery, html

My codes are :

HTML,

```
Date : <input id="datepicker">
Fare : <input id="fare">
```

JS,

```
<script>
     $(function(){
        $("#datepicker" ).datepicker({
           changeMonth: true,
           changeYear: true,
           showAnim: 'clip',
           dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" 
        }).val();
    });


    $("#datepicker").click(function() {
        if (confirm("If you change the Date the Fare fields data will be deleted !!")) {
            $('#fare').val('');
        } else {
            return false;
            $("#datepicker").datepicker('destroy');
        }
    });
<script>
```

I am trying to stop the datepicker when I cancel the confirmation box. Unfortunetly its not working. help please.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning false and then destroy the datepicker.

It should be reverse. Try this:

```
$( "#datepicker").click(function() {
    if (confirm("If you change the Date the Fare fields data will be deleted !!")) {

        $('#fare').val('');

    }else{
        $("#datepicker").datepicker('destroy');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, destroy then do `return false`,

```
<script>
 $(function(){
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
       changeMonth: true,
       changeYear: true,
       showAnim: 'clip',
       dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" 
    }).val();
});


$( "#datepicker").click(function() {
    if (confirm("If you change the Date the Fare fields data will be deleted !!")) {
        $('#fare').val('');
    }else{
        $("#datepicker").datepicker('destroy');
        return false;
    }
});
```